# Kivy update plot on press button

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

Starting to learn Kivy and can not update the graph on the button. Ideally, in the future, data should come from outside and be added to the graph without pressing any keys.Tried to use Clock.schedule_interval but it didn't work.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.clock import Clock

x=2
y=4
lst=[x,y]
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

class MainApp(App):

    def update(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.plot,1)
        
    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        for i in range(20):
            global y
            global x
            global lst
            x=x*2
            y=y*2
            lst.append(x)
            lst.append(y)
            print(lst)

        return MainApp.build(self)
        print('Button pressed!')
    
    def build(self):
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(lst)
        plt.ylabel('some numbers')
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        grid_layout=GridLayout(cols=1,
                               row_force_default=True,
                               row_default_height=100,
                               size_hint=(.2,1)
                               )
        main_layout.add_widget(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text='Hello from Kivy'))

        button1=grid_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1', on_press=self.on_press_button))

        main_layout.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(), size_hint=(.8,1)))
        print ('build called')
        return main_layout
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `build()` method of an `App` is called automatically when you call the `run()` method of the `App`, and the widget returned by `build()` is set as the `root` widget of the `App`. If you call that same `build()` method directly, it does not affect the `root` widget of the `App`.

One way to accomplish what you want is to create a new method that does the plotting and returns an instance of `FigureCanvasKivyAgg`. This new method can be called inside the `build()` method, and can also be called in the `on_press_button()` method and the returned `FigureCanvasKivyAgg` can then be used to replace the original. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 2
y = 4
lst = [x, y]
plt.ylabel('some numbers')


class MainApp(App):

    def build_plt(self):
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(lst)
        plt.ylabel('some numbers')
        return FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf(), size_hint=(.8,1))

    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        for i in range(20):
            global y
            global x
            global lst
            x = x * 2
            y = y * 2
            lst.append(x)
            lst.append(y)
            print(lst)

        # return MainApp.build(self)
        self.root.remove_widget(self.fcka)  # remove the current plot
        self.fcka = self.build_plt()  # create the updated plot
        self.root.add_widget(self.fcka)  # insert the new plot
        print('Button pressed!')

    def build(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        grid_layout=GridLayout(cols=1,
                               row_force_default=True,
                               row_default_height=100,
                               size_hint=(.2,1)
                               )
        main_layout.add_widget(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text='Hello from Kivy'))

        button1=grid_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1', on_press=self.on_press_button))
        self.fcka = self.build_plt()

        main_layout.add_widget(self.fcka)
        print ('build called')
        return main_layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Man, u are the best! It works. Thanks for explanation :)